# Is it possible to have multiple actions in forms using only one submit button?

Tags: php, forms

See question -
I've tried this:

```
echo "<form action='index.php' method='post'>   
Use the previous input of participants: <input type='radio' name='participants[]'value='$participants[0]'> 
OR <br>
<form action='index.html' method='post'>
Use a different input of participants: <input type='radio' name='participants[]' value='0'>
<input type='submit' value='send' name='send'> </form> <br>";
```

Both of the radio button lead me to index.php when I want to be able to go to index.html in case i press on the second radio button.

Comment: No, you would need one form and some JS to see which radio is checked and submit to proper page.  Or more normal submit to index.php, check which radio was submitted and either stay on index.php or redirect to index.html or similar.

Comment: I can't use if-statements, because that way I can't submit the variable to index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may solve it by using JQuery

```
<form action='index.php' method='post'>   
    Use the previous input of participants: 
    <input type='radio' name='participants[]' value='$participants[0]'> 
    <br/>OR <br> 
    Use a different input of participants: 
    <input type='radio' name='participants[]' value='0'>
    <input type='submit' value='send' name='send'> 
</form> 

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form  = $('form');
    var input = $('input[type=radio]');
    input.on('click', function() { 
        if ($(this).val()==0) { 
            form.prop('action', 'index.html');
        } else {  
            form.prop('action', 'index.php');
        } 
    }); 
});
</script>
```